# How to ensure two .NET versions are shown on top of my NuGet page?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nugetgallery

I have a question about [this NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConnectingApps.Xunit.TestLogger/1.0.1-preview). Right, now .NET 6 is shown on top. But, as you can see in the [Frameworks tab](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConnectingApps.Xunit.TestLogger/1.0.1-preview#supportedframeworks-body-tab), .NET 6 and .NET 7 are both supported. How should I change my csproj (or do something else) to ensure both versions are shown on top?

Here is my csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net7.0;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Title>Xunit.TestLogger</Title>
    <Company>Connecting Apps</Company>
    <Description>See the output of your logging in your xUnit integration tests</Description>
    <Copyright>© 2023 Connecting Apps. All rights BLAH BLAH </Copyright> 
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/ConnectingApps/Xunit.TestLogger</PackageProjectUrl>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/ConnectingApps/Xunit.TestLogger</RepositoryUrl>
    <RepositoryType>git</RepositoryType>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>Initial version</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    <PackageIcon>Icon.png</PackageIcon>
    <Version>1.0.1-preview</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Package Icon -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="Icon.png" Pack="True" PackagePath="" />
    </ItemGroup>

     <!-- ScreenForLogging (screenshot for README) -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="..\ScreenForLogging.png" Pack="True" PackagePath="" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Readme File -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="..\README.md">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- NuGet packages for net6.0 -->
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'">
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="[6.0.0, 6.0.99]" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.abstractions" Version="[2.0.3, 3.2.0]" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- NuGet packages for net7.0 -->
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0'">
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="[7.0.0, 7.0.99]" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.abstractions" Version="[2.0.3, 3.2.0]" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

NuGet is open source, including the nuget.org website, so let's investigate.

Right clicking the .NET 6.0 badge on nuget.org for your package, and selecting inspect shows me the HTML for the page, and has taken me straight to the badge's HTML. Looking at the parent node, it says `<div class="framework framework-badges">`. That `framework-badges` sounds unique enough to search for in the source.

Now, going to https://github.com/NuGet, in the pinned repos the description for NuGetGallery says "powers https://www.nuget.org", so I go to https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery, and then in search I enter `framework-badges`, taking me to [this search results page](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ANuGet%2FNuGetGallery+framework-badges&type=code). It only finds two hits, one in the stylesheet, and the other in the razor page: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/blob/ccb8999176522acb1d06baa3c3cd5757af519b45/src/NuGetGallery/Views/Packages/_SupportedFrameworksBadges.cshtml#L5

Looking at this page, I see 4 `@if` statements, but no loops. The 4 if statements are for some generic "net", followed by netcore, netstandard and netframework. So, it looks like it's only possible to show a single badge per framework identifier.

At the top of the page, it says `@model PackageFrameworkCompatibilityBadges`, so I open the file that defines the class: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/blob/main/src/NuGetGallery.Core/Frameworks/PackageFrameworkCompatibilityBadges.cs

It defines a single `NuGetFramework` instance for each of these 4 properties, and searching for where [the class is instantiated and populated](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/blob/ccb8999176522acb1d06baa3c3cd5757af519b45/src/NuGetGallery.Core/Frameworks/PackageFrameworkCompatibilityFactory.cs#L157-L184), we can see `.Select(d => d.Framework).FirstOrDefault()`.

Therefore, nuget.org will only show a single badge per "framework" (.NET Standard, .NET (Core), and .NET Framework). Since net6.0 and net7.0 are both `.NETCoreApp`, nuget.org will only show one of these at the top of the page. But if you click the frameworks tab, you'll see it shows all the frameworks that your package is compatible with.

Comment: .NET 5 and .NET Core 3.1 are also both `NETCoreApp` , right? But these can be shown together https://www.nuget.org/packages/WireMock.Net

Comment: It might be that the person who worked on nuget.org's frameworks feature didn't know. What I think is more likely is that they chose to show netcoreapp 1.0 to 3.1 separately from net5+ because people new to .NET generally will not know that net5+ is really netcoreapp under the covers. Since netcoreapp3.1 is already unsupported, the fact that net5+ is really netcoreapp is now just trivia that isn't particularly useful knowledge.